# Getting error while trying to connect azure cloud shell in vs code

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cloud-shell

I need to run cloud shell commands, In azure portal i am able to use cloud shell with out any problem but the main thing is I want it in vscode, I have installed the vscode and tried to connect to azure but getting an error in my vscode.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaULO.jpg)
Im getting the following error.

```
Requesting a Cloud Shell...
Connecting terminal...
Error: Socket is closed
```

I have tried the following az login command but still not able to figure out.

```
az login -u abc@outlook.com -p WOrk4@zure
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried the following az login command but still not able to figure out.

[image]

- Install the above azure cli extension you can find it in azure developer tools.
- And then open azure cli terminal and type the following command

```
az login
```

[image]
And then login with your azure subscription credentials.
Performed the same and was successfully able to run cli in vs code.

[image]

Refer this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli) for more information.